# Mix two arrays. Simple. Python

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say that I have these two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1])
b = np.array([2,2,2])
```

How can I "mix" then to obtain the following:

```
c = np.array([1,2,1,2,1,2])
```

Does it exist a function like `np.concatenate`, `np.repeat`, `np.tile` which I can use or I will have to make my own one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the prettiest, but you can do this:

```
>>> np.array(zip(a,b)).flatten()
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

You would however have to do the below in `Python3`:

```
np.array(list(zip(a,b))).flatten()
```

As `zip` no longer returns a list, but rather a generator (similar to `range`).

Athough just for the record, it appears the fastest way is probably how John La Rooy suggested (using transpose then flatten):

```
$ python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; a = np.array(range(30)); b = np.array(range(30)); c = np.array(zip(a,b)).flatten()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; a = np.array(range(30)); b = np.array(range(30)); c = np.array([a, b]).T.flatten()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'import numpy as np; a = np.array(range(30)); b = np.array(range(30)); c = np.vstack([a, b]).T.ravel()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 usec per loop
```

Comment: I was gonna recommend `np.resize(zip(a,b),(1,6))` and this is certainly prettier than that

Comment: Note that this will not work in python3. you will need  `np.array(list(zip(a, b))).flatten()`

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley :)

Comment: @user3100115 Good point. I didn't test that yet but I'll put it in the answer after I do.

Comment: and the same thing apply for @Joran suggestion where you will need this: `np.resize(list(zip(a,b)),(1,6)).flatten()`

Comment: I think using `zip` on `np.array` and back again is wasting a lot of cpu cycles. Why not `np.array([a, b]).T.flatten()`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another one-liner:

```
np.vstack([a, b]).T.ravel()
```

or similarly

```
np.vstack([a, b]).ravel('F')
```

or you could do

```
np.concatenate(list(zip(a, b)))
```

endless possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

from the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

This is verbose, but has the advantage that it will take iterables of different lengths.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

also read this heres more info about it
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: This returns `array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`